# PHP use glob() inside MySQLi while loop

Tags: php, glob

On my website's dashboard, I use a while loop to retrieve data from a DB and echo each record. Inside this while loop, I use `glob()` to show all the images inside the specific folder, which is a column in my DB table, `$record["folder"]`.

This is the code I use:

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

   {

            $directory = '../send-us-your-photos/media/'.$record['folder'];
            chdir($directory);
            $images = glob("*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach($images as $image) {
                echo '<div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="'.$directory.'/'.$image.'" />
                        <div>'.$image.'</div>                              
                      </div>'; 
            } 

   }
```

Now, the first record works fine and is showing the images in the specific folder. But the next records all show the same `$image` data but for a different folder.

**So for example:**

Record 1: folder 1 - shows image1.jpg

Record 2: folder 2 - tries to find same image1.jpg in folder 2

Record 3: folder 3 - tries to find same image1.jpg in folder 3

**What I need:**

Record 1: folder 1 - shows images in folder 1

Record 2: folder 2 - shows images in folder 2

Record 3: folder 3 - shows images in folder 3

---

How should I change my code so it shows the correct images in each record?

Comment: After you chdir the first time, the relative path might be wrong. Can you confirm that chdir returns true (indicating success) each time?

Comment: @sunil thanks for the suggestion, the `chdir` was indeed causing the problem. But it's fixed now thanks to Hassan Ahmed's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply , don't change your directory , and use your directory path directly in glob function

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $directory = '../send-us-your-photos/media/'.$record['folder'];
    // chdir($directory);
    $images = glob($directory . "/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="'.$directory.'/'.$image.'" />
        <div>'.$image.'</div>                              
        </div>'; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's down to your chdir statement. You are going down one folder `..` then up to `send-us-your-photos/media/_FOLDER_`.

So the next time you start off in `send-us-your-photos/media/_FOLDER_` and go back one folder `..` to `send-us-your-photos/media/` and then it tries to go to `send-us-your-photos/media/send-us-your-photos/media/_FOLDER_` and obviously fails.

It doesn't look like it's failing because you're outputting the value of `$directory` which you set yourself. Try outputting `getcwd()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem had indeed something to do with the `chdir`. The answer by Hassan Ahmed did the trick.